# Insert Statement error, ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Tags: sql, oracle

any help guys I got error column not allowed here for datetime !

```
INSERT INTO MEMBERS_CONTRIBUTIONS (
    CONTRIBUTION_TYPE,
    FROM_DATE,
    TO_DATE,
    ADDED_PERIOD_IN_MONTHS,
    MEMBER_AMOUNT,
    THE_CURRENCY,
    MATURITY_DATE
) VALUES (
    4,
    convert(datetime, '6/1/2016 12:00:00 AM', 5),
    convert(datetime, '6/1/2016 12:00:00 AM', 5),
    0,
    2500,
    'OMR',
    convert(datetime, '6/30/2016 12:00:00 AM', 5)
);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `CONVERT`? In oracle, it is used to convert a character string from one character set to another.

Comment: I want to insert date with full format dd/mm/yyyy ss:mm:hh

Comment: take a look at the to_date-function

Comment: Where in the Oracle manual did you find the `convert()` function? And where in the manual did you find the `datetime` data type?

Comment: Try to use to_char(sysdate,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')

Comment: @AvrajitRoy: **no**. `to_char()` converts a `date` to a `varchar` in this case `to_date()` is needed to convert a `varchar` to a (real) `date`

Comment: See the manual on how to properly provide a date literal: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yupps correct I thought he is storing the date as VARCHAR in table to used to_char. If date is only stored then yes we can use TO_DATE function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the [SQL Server `CONVERT()` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx) in Oracle - the [Oracle `CONVERT()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions027.htm) converts from one character-set to another and does not do what you want.

Instead, you can use a date literal:

```
INSERT INTO MEMBERS_CONTRIBUTIONS (
    CONTRIBUTION_TYPE,
    FROM_DATE,
    TO_DATE,
    ADDED_PERIOD_IN_MONTHS,
    MEMBER_AMOUNT,
    THE_CURRENCY,
    MATURITY_DATE
) VALUES (
    4,
    DATE '2016-06-01',
    DATE '2016-06-01',
    0,
    2500,
    'OMR',
    DATE '2016-06-30'
);
```

In Oracle, all `DATE` types have both a date and time component - the date literal syntax will just set the time component to `00:00:00` (or `12:00:00 AM` in a 12 hour clock).

Or if you want to specify the time component then you can use the timestamp literal (which Oracle will implicitly cast to a `DATE` type if that is the type of the column you are storing it in):

```
INSERT INTO MEMBERS_CONTRIBUTIONS (
    CONTRIBUTION_TYPE,
    FROM_DATE,
    TO_DATE,
    ADDED_PERIOD_IN_MONTHS,
    MEMBER_AMOUNT,
    THE_CURRENCY,
    MATURITY_DATE
) VALUES (
    4,
    TIMESTAMP '2016-06-01 00:00:00',
    TIMESTAMP '2016-06-01 00:00:00',
    0,
    2500,
    'OMR',
    TIMESTAMP '2016-06-30 00:00:00'
);
```

Or you could explicitly cast a string literal to a date using the `TO_DATE()` function:

```
INSERT INTO MEMBERS_CONTRIBUTIONS (
    CONTRIBUTION_TYPE,
    FROM_DATE,
    TO_DATE,
    ADDED_PERIOD_IN_MONTHS,
    MEMBER_AMOUNT,
    THE_CURRENCY,
    MATURITY_DATE
) VALUES (
    4,
    TO_DATE( '6/1/2016 12:00:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM' ),
    TO_DATE( '6/1/2016 12:00:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM' ),
    0,
    2500,
    'OMR',
    TO_DATE( '6/30/2016 12:00:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM' )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression `convert(datetime, '6/1/2016 12:00:00 AM', 5)` calls for a column with the name `datetime`. But your insert statement doesn't offer a context involving any columns at all, so the query parser can't make any sense of `datetime`. Hence your [ORA-00948](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00984_column_not_allowed.htm) error.

I guess you're trying to put a date/time constant, which from your example could mean either 1-Jun-2016 or 6-Jan-2016, into a [`date`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i1847) datatype. You need to use the [`TO_DATE()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2114.htm) function to convert your strings to that format. I'm not going to suggest a particular form of the call, because I don't know exactly how your strings are formatted.